# this.options.components?.map is not a function Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

> this.options.components?.map is not a function

I've looked online but can't find an answer as most of the solutions are to update node.js of which I have the latest version

````
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, Component } = require('discord.js');
function makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
            charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}
module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('script')
    .setDescription('รับสคริป'),
execute: async (interaction, con, log, client, config) => {
    log(`[LOG Command] ${interaction.user.username}, use command getscript`, "green")
    const user = interaction.options.getUser('user');

    const menu = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId("SELRCTION")
        .addOptions(
            { label: "BloxFruit", description: "script BloxFruit ", value: "BF", emoji: ""},
        ),
    );
       
    /*interaction.relpy({ content: "You Select ", ephemeral: true, components: {menu}});*/
    await con.query(`SELECT userkey, discord_id,Blacklisted FROM bloxfruit Where discord_id = '${interaction.user.id}'`, async function(err, results, fields) {
    if(!results[0]) {
        await interaction.reply({ 
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#FF0000")
                .setTitle('**"WET HUB" | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                .setDescription("คุณไม่มีไวริสนะคะ กรุณาก่อนใช้ด้วยค่ะ")
                .setTimestamp()
            ],
            ephemeral: true
        })
    } else {
     if(results[0].Blacklisted == "True") {
        await interaction.reply({ 
            embeds: [
                new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#FF0000")
                .setTitle('**WET HUB | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                .setDescription("คุณอยู่ในบัญชีดำนะคะ")
                .setTimestamp()
            ],
            ephemeral: true
        })
     } else {
        let key = results[0].userkey
        let discord_id = results[0].discord_id
        await interaction.reply({ content: "You Select ", ephemeral: true, components: {menu}})
        if (value == "BF") {
            await interaction.reply({
                embeds: [
                    new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor("00FF46")
                    .setTitle('**WET HUB | ᴡʜɪᴛᴇʟɪsᴛ ᴍᴀɴᴀɢᴇʀ**')
                    .setDescription('```lua\ngetgenv().Key = "'+ key + '"\ngetgenv().DiscordId = "'+ discord_id + '"\nloadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Galiverking/CheckPointWT/main/check-lua.lua"))()```')
                    .setTimestamp()
                ], 
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
        
    };
     }
  })
}
````

}

This is my code, but for some reason, it's returning a mapping error even though I'm not using the inbuilt function and is returning this error:

```
   C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:137
    const components = this.options.components?.map(c => (isJSONEncodable(c) ? c : new ActionRowBuilder(c)).toJSON());
                                            ^

TypeError: this.options.components?.map is not a function
at MessagePayload.resolveBody (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:137:49)
at ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:109:56)
at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\commands\getscript.js:57:31)
at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
at Sequence.end (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\user\Documents\BOT WHITELIST PACK\main\slash_BOT\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)

Node.js v19.6.1
```

Comment: I think that is a typo in the referenced package (discord.js). Try another version.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out my answer below? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

[`components`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BaseMessageOptions) should be an array, not an object. You'll need to update the `interaction.reply` like this:

```js
await interaction.reply({
  content: "You Select",
  ephemeral: true,
  components: [menu],
})
```